# Como comprobar si la fecha actual es mayor que una fecha guardada mas dias? SQLServer

Tags: c#, sql

Veréis, ando con un proyecto de clase en el que, en cierta funcion, tengo que comprobar si la fecha actual es mayor que una fecha almacenada + 3 dias y si esta condicion se cumple, mostrar X titulos en rojo (Para poneros en contexto, es un videoclub)
Ya tengo el código en C# y la lógica me dice que funcionaria para lo que quiero hacer, pero el problema viene en que no se como decirle a SQL que me devuelva las los registros que cumplan exactamente esa condición.
Os dejo por aquí un pequeño fragmento del código a ver si alguien me echa una mano.

**CODIGO**

```
        query = "SELECT * FROM ALQUILERES WHERE IDCLIENTES = " + idCliente;
        redVideoClub.Open();
        comando = new SqlCommand(query, redVideoClub);
        registro = comando.ExecuteReader();
        while (registro.Read())
        {
            Alquiler a1 = new Alquiler() { IDPelicula = Convert.ToInt32(registro[1].ToString()), IDCliente = Convert.ToInt32(registro[2].ToString()), FechaALQ = Convert.ToDateTime(registro[3].ToString()) };
            ListaAlquileres.Add(a1);
            DateTime fechaVenc = a1.FechaALQ.AddDays(2);

            if(a1.FechaENTR == null && DateTime.Today > fechaVenc)
            {
                query = "SELECT IDPELICULAS FROM ALQUILERES WHERE GETDATE() > FECHAALQ"//IGNORAD ESTA LINEA, ES LA QUERY EN LA QUE LE TENGO QUE HACER LA PETICIÓN A LA BBDD Y NO SÉ EXACTAMENTE COMO HACERLO
            }
        }
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Tu código está bien solo te falta tu SQL:

Que sería más o menos así:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM ALQUILERES WHERE IDCLIENTES = " + idCliente;
redVideoClub.Open();
comando = new SqlCommand(query, redVideoClub);
registro = comando.ExecuteReader();
while (registro.Read())
{
    Alquiler a1 = new Alquiler() { IDPelicula = Convert.ToInt32(registro[1].ToString()), IDCliente = Convert.ToInt32(registro[2].ToString()), FechaALQ = Convert.ToDateTime(registro[3].ToString()) };
    ListaAlquileres.Add(a1);
    DateTime fechaVenc = a1.FechaALQ.AddDays(2);

    if(a1.FechaENTR == null && DateTime.Today > fechaVenc)
    {
        query = "SELECT IDPELICULAS FROM ALQUILERES WHERE DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), FECHAALQ) >= 3"; //La función date diff hace una resta entre las fechas que le proporcionas en este caso day 'Días' 
    }
}
```

Espero que te sirva.

Saludos.

Comment: Ni idea de por que pero el query que me has dejado aqui no me devolvia nigun tipo de valor. De todas maneras es algo que ya he solucionado, muchas gracias!